# How to use VCL as a separate namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, vector-class-library

My goal is to separate all vectorclass-library typenames to a separate namespace, so that vcl::Vec4i will compile, but Vec4i won't. I tried to use example from manual, however it's not working.

Failed attempt [following the manual](https://www.agner.org/optimize/vcl_manual.pdf#page=60&zoom=100,94,422):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vcl/vectorclass.h"
#define VCL_NAMESPACE vcl
using namespace vcl; //error
int main() {
 vcl::Vec4i vec; //error
 Vec4i vec; //still compiles
 return 0;
}
```

Failure message:

```
root@vlad:/avx_vcl clang++ -std=c++17 -mavx -o test main.cpp 
main.cpp:4:17: error: expected namespace name
using namespace vcl;
                ^
main.cpp:6:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'vcl'
        vcl::Vec4i vec;
        ^
2 errors generated.
```

Desired result:

```
#define VCL_NAMESPACE vcl
int main() {
 vcl::Vec4i vec; //compiles
 Vec4i vec; //won't compile
 return 0;
}
```

What should I change?

Comment: The line `using namespace vcl;` seems to be contrary to the stated goal. By importing all the names, both code versions will still compile.

Comment: @BoP Doing it inside an example `.cpp` file isn't too bad. The point is probably to not pollute the global namespace with the vcl stuff, so as long as OP doesn't do `using namespace vcl;` inside the global namespace in header files, I think it's fine.

Comment: Yes, I've clarified this moment in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in chapter `2.7 Using a namespace`, you need to `define VCL_NAMESPACE` before including any `vcl` headers, directly or indirectly, so change the order to:

```cpp
#define VCL_NAMESPACE vcl
#include "vcl/vectorclass.h"   // this line after the #define
using namespace vcl;           // ...and now this will work
```

---

If we look inside `vectori128.h` which defines `Vec4i` we see that all of the definitions in the file are surrounded by an `#ifdef VCL_NAMESPACE` pair:

```cpp
#ifdef VCL_NAMESPACE
namespace VCL_NAMESPACE {
#endif
```

```
// all the definitions, including Vec4i
```

```cpp
#ifdef VCL_NAMESPACE
}
#endif
```

So, what happens is that if you *don't* define `VCL_NAMESPACE` before including any of those headers, it will *not* put them in the namespace you've selected.

**Note** - You need to put this `#define VCL_NAMESPACE vcl` **first** in *all* your files that include any `vcl` header, directly or indirectly. It may be easiest to give the compiler the instruction to just define it always. `g++` example:

```
g++ -DVCL_NAMESPACE=vcl ...
```